# JSFiddle external resources not working

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

I am new to jsfiddle and I am trying to link my external resources.

I added them using the tab on the left side and then paste my code on the panes

[Here is my JSFiddle project](http://jsfiddle.net/8xhGw/) but only html is shown without linking to javascript and css in the output

what I am doing wrong ?

this is my original

```
<head>



    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-tagsinput.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/datepicker.css">

</head>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are issues with your fiddle

1. HTML panel is to place HTML Body tag only
2. You're using $(document).ready() along with "onLoad" setting

Please read http://doc.jsfiddle.net if in doubt.

Answer (score 5):

In **jsfiddle.net** resources can be added by giving its Content Delivery Networks (CDNs).

We can add jQuery plugin as external resource like:

`//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js`

Comment: so adding a direct link address won't work ??
something like this
http://download1508.mediafire.com/k1hg0mku7p6g/rb8prkbt7rb0vxe/jquery.tagit.css

Comment: No you can't add like that.

Comment: @super: Thanks for posting this answer you solved my problem, but I can't find that you need to add `//` infront of your link in the [JSfiddle documentation](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html#external-resources). Could you explain why these parentheses are needed?

Comment: Using `//' at the beginning of the address is the same as specifying `https://` if the page it is on is `https:`, or `http://` if it's on a `http:` page, and likewise for `ftp:`, `gopher:` or other (possibly future) protocol.  Just like a path starting with `/` is absolute to the server root, but relative to (i.e. same server as ) the page it's on,  so `//ajax.googleapis.com/` is absolute in terms of servers, but relative in terms of protocol.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I added the following to the element which moved to next line.

```
margin:-1;
```

And it came up for Chrome and left no effects on other browsers. Hope it helps.